# Pandas: Handle Unseen Data In Test

Tags: python, pandas

I have a training dataset and am building some machine learning models.  I don't have access to the test set and want to handle the possibility that one of the categorical features in test wasn't observed in train.

Here's a toy example illustrating what I mean:

I have a DataFrame, `old`, like this:

```
old = pd.DataFrame({"car":["Audi", "BMW", "Mazda"]})
```

Which looks like this:

```
    car
0   Audi
1   BMW
2   Mazda
```

I now one-hot encode like this:

```
new = pd.get_dummies(old)
```

and get back:

```
   car_Audi car_BMW car_Mazda
0      1       0       0
1      0       1       0
2      0       0       1
```

This is all good.  However, if I encounter a row in test that looks like:

```
    car
0   Mercedes
```

I can one-hot encode, but I'll end up with a column that I didn't have in test.

Is there a way in Pandas to just ignore values in test that I haven't seen in train?

So the desired output for my Mercedes row would be:

```
   car_Audi car_BMW car_Mazda
0      0       0       0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using `reindex` to achieve this

```
old = pd.DataFrame({"car":["Audi", "BMW", "Mazda"]})
new = pd.get_dummies(old)
test= pd.DataFrame({"car":["Audi", "BMW", "Mazda","Mercedes"]})
pd.get_dummies(test).reindex(columns=new.columns)
Out[460]: 
   car_Audi  car_BMW  car_Mazda
0         1        0          0
1         0        1          0
2         0        0          1
3         0        0          0 # row 3 will be all 0 after modified
```